# Error updating EDMX file

Tags: entity-framework, edmx

I've seen some other posts about this, but none of the answers seem to help. I'm trying to add a stored procedure to an EDMX. I open the diagram, right-mouse-click, and choose "Update Model from Database." I choose "Yes" for including sensitive data and I uncheck the "Save connection settings in App.config." (This EDMX is inside a class library that's sole purpose is housing this EDMX). I click Next, and choose the "Add" tab. I expand "Stored Procedures and Functions" and then find and click the checkbox for my stored proc. I only check the "Import selected stored procedures and functions into the entity model" and click "Finish." The error I receive is:

```
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred while attempting to update from the database. The exception message is 'Identifier is null or empty!".
```

I save the diagram. I search the entire solution for the name of my proc, and it only exists in the code that is trying to call it - there is no instance inside the EDMX.

The stored proc definition looks like this:

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[spGetCountableResult]
    @PatientId BIGINT
AS
```

My connection string looks like this:

```
<add name="DB_Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.DBContext.csdl|res://*/Models.DBContext.ssdl|res://*/Models.DBContext.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=DB.com;initial catalog=MyDb;user id=MyUser;password=MyPassword;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

My package.config entry is:

```
<package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net45" />
```

Anyone know what's going wrong here?

V

Comment: I had the same issue. In the end I was able to manufacture a workaround by removing some of the stored procedure until EF would import it; replacing the removed portion of stored procedure and then refreshing the model from the database. The 'offending' part of the procedure is perfectly legit and works for other stored procedures just fine :(

Comment: Not only the signature but also the body of the stored procedure matters, as well as the model class you use to capture its results.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is probably that your procedure performs SELECTs without naming all the columns.

See this: http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1529

If you procedure has something like `SELECT 1`, you will get the "Identifier is null or empty!" error. But if it was `SELECT 1 as 'One'` then it should work.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and after narrowing down which sproc was causing the issue, I realized I had some nested procedures in my failing procedure. I commented out the nested procedures, updated the model, then uncommented them later.

This wasn't a permanent solution, but it 'works in a pinch'.

Answer (score 0):

After pending hours I found the solution

There must be some SP with IF EXISTS or related check on some entity which is not present e.g some #tempTable etc.

Make sure that all the objects are available for EF even with NULL values then execute it will work.

For me it was one out of 200+ SPs causing all the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Try not to use stored procedure with #user or ##global temp tables. if you are unable to escape, try with output parameter or return explicit 0.

Answer (score -1):

If you have Error while adding a stored procedure to an EDMX :
An exception of type `System.ArgumentException` occurred while attempting to update from the database. The exception message is "Identifier is null or empty!".

Then you can add just set FMTONLY off in stored procedure

```
BEGIN
    Set FMTONLY off;
END
```

Comment: [Do not use this feature.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-fmtonly-transact-sql).

Comment: @GertArnold Sir ! , can you tell me reason ?

Comment: My comment is a link :)

Comment: @GertArnold ok , Thanks :) but temporary it worked for me !