# Identifier is Null or empty, entity framework, Update data base

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, ssms, updatemodel

I'm trying to update my model to add a new stored proc. However, I get the following error message when I try to.

[image]

This is the stored proc I'm trying to add

```
    BEGIN

        SET @result = 1;

        /* Execute first-pass validation rules. */
        EXECUTE [RulesEngine].[LGC_Validate_Rules] @passLevel = '1', @currentUserID = @current_user_id;

        /* Execute transformation rules. */
        -- None

        /* Execute second-pass validation rules. */
        EXECUTE [RulesEngine].[LGC_Validate_Rules] @passLevel = '2', @currentUserID = @current_user_id;

        RETURN
    END

GO
```

Any clues?

Comment: This looks like some Visual Studio bug to me. The SQL looks fine. Have you tried restarting the IDE?

Comment: Yes, I did that.

Comment: Can you put procedure contents inside `LGC_Validate_Rules` and parameters you want to pass in current SP? Seems that you have executing SP from EF which contains another SP, you need to use `SELECT` and mention column names to populate SP results with EF.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/41506386/3538246

"The problem is probably that your procedure performs SELECTs without naming all the columns."

The same thing happened to me.